# How to pass #file, #line, #column, #funcion to my ErrorLogger in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I constructed an ErrorLogger as shown below to make sure all error messages and user errors will be logged uniformly. However, initializing the struts when calling the ErrorLogger is very wordy at this point.

I would like to make it as simple as possible.

As you can see in my example below in the call where I am initializing ErrorLocation, I am having to type

`ErrorLocation(filePath: #file, line: #line, column: #column, funcName: #function)`

I would like to be able to save some typing and not have to re-type this over and over in my `Service class` whenever I want to log an error.

Are there better ways of doing this? I am open to suggestions.

***Using ErrorLogger***

```
func saveUserProfile(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, String>,completion: @escaping (Result<String>) -> Void) {

        // Save user profile data to the Firebase database - A User is born.
        firebaseDatabase.child(kUSER).child(uid).updateChildValues(user, withCompletionBlock: { (error: Error?, ref: DatabaseReference) in
            if error != nil {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!

                let logError = LogError(errorCode: kSAVING_USER_PROFILE_ERROR_CODE, errorLocation: ErrorLocation(filePath: #file, line: #line, column: #column, funcName: #function), description: "An error occurred while writing the user profile data to the firebase database", errorMessage: "\(error.debugDescription)")
                let userError = UserError(errorMessage: kSAVING_USER_PROFILE_ERROR_MESSAGE)
                return completion(.Error(errorCode: kSAVING_USER_PROFILE_ERROR_CODE, logError: logError, userError: userError))
            } else {
                // The user has been written to the database - A User has been born.
                return completion(.Success("The user was successfully written to the database"))
            }
        })
    }
```

***Console output ***

```
  2018-03-10 18:35:30 PM  ::Error::errorCode:: 4021 ::class::UserFBService.swift 
::functionName::fetchCurrentUserProfile(completion:) ::lineNumber::69 
::columnName162  ::UserID::ZE2837447f9tQ0i1z1AHHAFFFWACbg2  ::description::
An error occurred while fetching the current user's profile, some of the 
user's profile data was missing from Firebase  ::errorMessage::
```

***ErrorLogger.swift***

```
enum Result<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Incomplete(T, errorCode: Int, logError: LogError, userError: UserError)
    case Error(errorCode: Int, logError: LogError?, userError: UserError?)
}

struct LogError {

    var timestamp: String
    var header: String
    var errorCode: Int
    var errorLocation: ErrorLocation
    var userID: String
    var description: String //describes the type of error
    var errorMessage: String //actual error returned by given function

    init(timestamp: String = "", header: String = "", errorCode: Int, errorLocation: ErrorLocation, userID: String = "", description: String, errorMessage: String) {

        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.header = header
        self.errorCode = errorCode
        self.errorLocation = errorLocation
        self.userID = userID
        self.description = " ::description::" + description
        self.errorMessage = " ::errorMessage::" + errorMessage

        if timestamp.isEmpty {
            self.timestamp = Date().currentUTCTimestamp
        }

        if header.isEmpty {
            self.header = " ::Error::errorCode::"
        }
        if userID.isEmpty {
            self.userID = getUserID()
        }
    }

    func getUserID() -> String {
        var userUID: String = ""
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            userUID = (Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid.isEmpty ? "" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
        } else {
            userUID = ""
        }
        let userUIDStr: String = " ::UserID::" + userUID
        return userUIDStr
    }

    func toString() -> String {
        let fullErrorMessageStr: String = "\(timestamp) \(header) \(errorCode) \(errorLocation.toString()) \(userID) \(description) \(errorMessage)"
        return fullErrorMessageStr
    }
}

struct ErrorLocation {
    var filePath: String
    var line: Int
    var column: Int
    var funcName: String

    init(filePath: String, line: Int, column: Int, funcName: String) {
        self.filePath = filePath
        self.line = line
        self.column = column
        self.funcName = funcName
    }

    func getClassNameFromFilePath() -> String{
        var className: String = ""
        if !filePath.isEmpty {
            let components = filePath.components(separatedBy: "/")
            className = components.isEmpty ? "" : components.last!
        }
        return className
    }

    func toString() -> String {
        let errorLocationStr: String = "::class::\(getClassNameFromFilePath()) ::functionName::\(funcName) ::lineNumber::\(line) ::columnName\(column)"
        return errorLocationStr
    }
}

struct UserError {

    var errorTitle: String
    var errorMessage: String

    init(errorTitle: String, errorMessage: String) { //use this function overloading to specify
        //a different error title when necessary
        self.errorTitle = errorTitle
        self.errorMessage = errorMessage
    }

    init(errorMessage: String) {
        self.errorTitle = kOOPS_USER_ERROR_TITLE //error title defaults to "Oops!" for most cases
        self.errorMessage = errorMessage
    }
}

extension Date {
    var currentUTCTimestamp: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"
        //formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use default argument values:

```
struct ErrorLocation {
    init(filePath: String = #file, line: Int = #line, column: Int = #column, funcName: String = #function) {
```

And call the initializer with no argument: `ErrorLocation()`. The compiler will infer the values for those argument from the call site.

Note that if the `ErrorLocation` instantiation happens down in the call hierarchy, you'll need to also forward these arguments, meaning every function should have these arguments, with these values, up to the point were you get out of your logger hierarchy.

So instead of

```
struct LogError {
    init(timestamp: String = "", header: String = "", errorCode: Int, errorLocation: ErrorLocation, userID: String = "", description: String, errorMessage: String) {
```

, you'll need something like this

```
struct LogError {
    init(timestamp: String = "", header: String = "", errorCode: Int, userID: String = "", description: String, errorMessage: String, filePath: String = #file, line: Int = #line, column: Int = #column, funcName: String = #function) {
        let errorLocation = ErrorLocation(filePath: filePath, line: lone, column: column, funcName: funcName)
        // rest of the initializer
```

Comment: I had created a function in ErrorLogger to do this earlier but the #file, #line, #column, #function values were from the error logger and now my service class.

Comment: @Maria9905 I updated my answer with a solution for that.